# Trying to make a channel creation command, but there is an error

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

so im trying to make a command that creates a support ticket channel for anyone who types -ticket  P.S. im not that great at coding like at all

```
    case 'ticket':
        message.guild.createChannel('ticket', 'text', [
            {
                id: message.guild.defaultRole.id,
                deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
            },
            {
                id: message.user.id,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
            },
        ]);
        const tembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setTitle('test')
            .addField('Success!', 'Ticket was created.')
            .setColor(0xff0000)
        message.channel.sendEmbed(tembed);
        break;
```

console says "cannot read property id of undefined"

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Hopefully we can help resolve your issue.

**Problem:** I notice for the `id` field of the second permission overwrite, you have `message.user.id`. However, there's no `user` property of a [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message). When your code tries to read the `id` property of `message.user`, it throws an error because the latter returns undefined.

**Solution:** Use the [`author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) property, like so:

```js
{
  id: message.author.id,
  allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
}
```